# Minimize creation of instances of UIVIewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I guess this is a Beginners Question, so thank you for your patience:

In viewControllerA, I call a lot of methods from viewControllerB.

Currently I'm using

```
viewcontrollerB * vcB= [[viewcontrollerB alloc] init];
[vcB doSomething];
```

I do that **over and over again** in my ViewControllerA, and that feels stupid.

So what would be the best approach here?

Can I make viewControllerB a property of viewControllerA?
Should I use delegate methods, and if so, how?

Looking forward to your insights

Comment: yes you can make property and delegate if you want pass data to viewcontroller A.

Comment: Note: class names should be Camel Case, viewcontrollerB should be ViewcontrollerB, just for better code readability.

Comment: I think this is more like an opinion based question. As a rule, if VC-A is parent of VC-B, VC-A will have an instance of VC-B, and can call the functions directly. VC-B should have a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there might actually be some issues related to your design approach. While you didn't specify what is the actual relation between those 2 view controllers, but even in this situation, I would say yes, you can have your second view controller as a property of the first one.
If you would have described better what kind of actions you perform and what is the relation between those 2 view controllers you could expect a more detailed and extended answer.
Seems that your second view controller is actually not being presented on screen and you just reuse some of its business methods. This is not the way it should be. You should decouple those methods in some other classes, which encapsulate that particular shared business behavior.

I would also suggest you get acknowledged with MVVM design patter which solves these and more other kind of issues: https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/mvvm/

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate.

In ViewControllerB.h:

```
@protocol ViewControllerBDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)doSomething;

@end


@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ViewControllerBDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In ViewControllerB.m

```
-(void)someMethod {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomething)]) {
            [self.delegate doSomething]; // will call delegate implement in delegate object.
        }
}
```

In ViewControllerA:

```
ViewControllerB *vcB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
vcB.delegate = self;

#pragma mark - ViewControllerBDelegate
-(void)doSomething {
    //...
}
```

You should call `[self.delegate doSomething]` in ViewControllerB when you want do something in ViewControllerA;